# Get the value of a select option in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

i have this user.model.ts, Ihave a list of users that I can edit by clicking on a button that filters the user's data and puts it in a modal of bootstrap, with the [ngModel] in select tag i can get the country of my user but when i change the country and submit the form I receive the current country but not its id, it should be noted that when I use [value] in the option it does not show me the current country, how can i get the value and not the name? Thanks.

in user.component.ts

```
updateUser(formActualizarTeam) {
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

in user.model.ts

```
export class UserModel{
 name: string;
 idCountry: number;
}
```

in user.component.html

```
<form
  #formUpdate="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="updateUser(formUpdate)">

<select
   id="country"
   name="idCountry"
   class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)]="user.idCountry">
   <option *ngFor="let c of countries">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Comment: can you show the countries array.,?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the `[value]` attribute to match the options to select `ngModel`

then the code will be (if you have  `idCountry` in **countries** array)

```
<select id="country" name="idCountry" class="form-control [(ngModel)]="user.idCountry">
   <option *ngFor='let c of countries' [value]='c.idCountry'>{{ c.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when I use [value] or [ngValue] in the option it does not show me the current country :(

Comment: [{"idCountry":1,"name":"Polonia"},{"idCountry":2,"name":"Malasia"},{"idCountry":3,"name":"Suecia"}]... it's a service

Comment: This should be done with above code if not then there will mismatch in your array data. if you need more help then consider showing full component code..

Comment: hey hello, I had a serious error in my array of users because the idcountry did not return a number if not a string, anyway thanks to you I realized that error, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You need bind `[value]` to `idCountry` , also to set default value the selected value should match some option value :

```
<select
   id="country"
   name="idCountry"
   class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)]="user.idCountry">
   <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c?.idCountry">{{ c?.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Also to load the default value there are two option:

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
this.user['idCountry'] =  this.countries[0]['id']; //  set this after country data is loaded
}
```

OR

```
this.user['idCountry'] = '';
```

**component.html**

```
<select
   id="country"
   name="idCountry"
   class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)]="user.idCountry">
   <option value="" [disabled]="true"> Select country</option> // set some placeholder
   <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c?.idCountry">{{ c?.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: when I use [value] in the option it does not show me the current country :(

Comment: @CarlosMorales you need to set the current country on  loading the data  ie : `his.user['idCountry']`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, could you detail me?

Comment: hi, i debug my aplication and found a serious error in my array of users because the idcountry did not return a number if not a string, anyway thanks to you I realized that error, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can get selected value by using (change) event.

In your html:

```
<select (change)="onChange($event)"
   id="country"
   name="idCountry"
   class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let c of countries">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select>
```

In you .ts:

```
onChange(e: any) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [value] for your option tag like below  **[value]="c.idCountry"**

```
<form
  #formUpdate="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="updateUser(formUpdate)">

<select
   id="country"
   name="idCountry"
   class="form-control"
   [(ngModel)]="user.idCountry">
   <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.idCountry">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select>

</form>
```

you will get value now try priting it

```
updateUser(ngform){
    console.log(ngform.form.value)
  }
```